# Sample size for desired margin of error with clusters of unequal size

Tags: sampling, sample-size, cluster-sample

I need to design a survey such that the margin of error for a binary, categorical variable is bounded at a certain level. The survey needs to be a one or two-stage cluster sample where *clusters are of unequal size*. For the purposes of this question, let's ignore nonresponse, etc.

#### Clusters of equal size

When you have clusters of equal (or approximately equal) size, this is relatively straight-forward. For example, for a one-stage cluster sample, as long as the number of clusters in the population is large (and clusters are of equal size), the maximum margin of error for a binary categorical variable is give by

$$
Margin \; of \; error \le z_{a/2} \cdot \sqrt{ \frac{P \cdot (1 - P)}{n} } \cdot \sqrt{1 + \rho \cdot (m - 1)}
$$

where $z_{a/2}$ is the critical value for a 95 percent confidence interval, $P$ is the proportion, $n$ is the sample size, $\rho$ is the interclass correlation coefficient, and $m$ is the size of each cluster. For the derivation of this formula see Lohr, *Sampling: Design and Analysis*, Second Edition (2019). Chapter 5.

To find an upper bound, we can set $P = 0.5$ as this maximizes the variance. In the case of a binary variable, the ICC likely falls between 0.01 and 0.2. And that's all we need.

This can be extended to the case of two-stage cluster sampling where clusters are of equal size.

#### Clusters of unequal size

Now the questions is what to do when clusters are not of equal size. A response to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122274/numbre-of-cluster-in-pps-sampling-method/123961#123961) suggests stratifying clusters by (approximate) size. Sometimes that works, but not always. When stratifying isn't an option, how can you estimate what (approximate) bound on the margin of error your sampling design provides (if any). I'm thinking particularly about two-stage cluster sampling where clusters are selected with probability proportionate to size and the sample size per cluster is fixed.

There a huge literature on this in regards to causal inference (RCTs). For example, see references [here](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0255389). Is there a standard approach in sampling theory though? Perhaps something related to the coefficient of variation for the cluster sizes? For example, is setting $m$ to the size of the largest cluster a heuristic or does it actually give you a conservative bound?

Thanks in advance for any help with understand this.

Comment: Substitute $m$ with $\bar m$, average cluster size? Yes, it's an approximation, but so are $P$ and $\rho$

Comment: @AlexJ but wouldn't that be a bad approximation? I thought you always had more variance with variable clusters sizes (everything else being the same), so this would always understimate the necessary sample size, no? And yes $\rho$ is an approximation but $P$ is an upper bound, not an approximation.

Comment: How are you planning to calculate your confidence interval?

Comment: @GeorgeSavva, I don't have an actual survey in mind. I just wrote it like this but it's a general question. For the context I'm imagining, I'd use a design based approach for the confidence interval.